# How can I use a single JSON file, with a single TWIG template, to create multiple html files with gulp

Tags: json, gulp

I am building a website, where I need to generate multiple pages, using the same TWIG template, but with different data coming from a single JSON file.

For example:

```
{   
  "john" : {
    "name": "John Smith",
    "phone": "+12345"
  }

  "bob" : {
    "name": "Bob Builder",
    "phone": "+12345"
  }
}
```

and then we would have one template in twig, which would then compile using gulp into something like this:

```
<h1>{{name}}</h1>
<p>{{phone}}</p>
```

For now, I just have multiple templates, with multiple corresponding JSON files, but it seems to be very messy.

*I tried searching here and on Google, but couldn't really find anything, as twig doesn't seem to be too popular.*

Comment: Not understanding your question. Twig is just a mere templating engine, if you want to serve multiple pages, u'd need to adjust your controller and create multiple routes. This is not something twig should account for, it's there to serve output

Comment: @DarkBee, I know that's why I have mentioned the gulp compilation. I know it's not to be done by twig, but by gulp.

Comment: You shouldn't tag with twig then, as this is a not a problem related to twig...